# Model is Null while passing by Ajax Call MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new bird in MVC. I want to pass the Model into the Ajax call, i write the following code to do so. But it always passing NULL to all properties.

```
   $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {

        alert('hello');
        var productModel = {
            Name: 'ram@mailinator.com',
            Address: "Chai"

        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("ContactDistributor", "AjaxCallTest")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ model: productModel }),

            dataType: "json",
            success: function () { alert('Success'); },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.error);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
```

MODEL :

```
    public class AjaxCalltestModal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set; }

}
```

Controller :

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ContactDistributor(WebApplication1.Models.AjaxCalltestModal a)
    {
        return Json("test");
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: `productModel` is already json, so you don't need `JSON.stringify` when posting data. And your controller accepts a parameter named `a` so your `data` should be `data: { a: productModel }`

Comment: use `JSON.stringify(productModel )`

Comment: Remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and change the `data` option to `data: productModel,`

Comment: Why Down vote??? Please comment down voters..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have resolved the Issue by using the following Code:

```
$("#btnsubmit").click(function () {

    alert('hello');
    var productModel = {
        Name: 'ram@mailinator.com',
        Address: "Chai"

    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ContactDistributor", "AjaxCallTest")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'model': productModel }),

        dataType: "json",
        success: function () { alert('Success'); },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.error);
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

Thanks for your efforts and comments..

Comment: your question and answer look identical.What exactly is the difference?

Comment: @GotaloveCode "  data: JSON.stringify({ model: productModel })," updated with   "data: JSON.stringify({ 'model' : productModel }),"

Comment: THe quotes !totally missed that

Answer (score 2):

```
JSON.stringify({ model: productModel })
```

should be

```
JSON.stringify(productModel)
```

Comment: You're my saviour dude!

Answer (score 2):

most probably setting data as a Javascript object will work instead of tyring to Stringify it. Because as far as i know, query ajax method already does this for you

```
data:  productModel
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but this might help someone in the future.  If you have a property in your model called "Model", the MVC parser doesn't seem to process it properly and it will also come back null.

Just rename it to anything else and it works properly.